# Tomcat - running on VPS

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, vps, ovh

I am trying to run tomcat 8 on my VPS (Debian 8.8) and I have the following problem:
During starting the tomcat:

```
sh startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

everything looks ok but tomcat still doesn't work and when I want to shutdown the server I receive this information:

```
sh shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
./catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/local/java/bin/java: not found
```

A few information about my environment:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

which java
/home/ovh/src/soft/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java

printenv
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java
PATH=/home/ovh/src/soft/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_131/bin
JAVA_HOME=/home/ovh/src/soft/jdk1.8.0_131
```

Comment: As your java is not installed in this directory, have you checked if there is an `/usr/local/java/bin/java` binary?

Comment: Yes, The problem exists with path but now I have this error: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user, which you are using for tomcat, has execute rights for 
:

- `/usr/local/java/bin/java`
- `/usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar`
- `/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar`

Comment: I change Debian to Ubuntu and everything works :) I don't know where was a problem on Debian. Thank for your help